# DateTime to UnixTime Stamp in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, unix-timestamp

Is there any function in vb dot net to  convert datetime to unix time stamp
If I google I get only the vice versa but not vb.net to unix time stamp

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 25, accepted):

{Edit} removed old reference link

Seconds since Jan 1, 1970 = unix time

To get this in VB.NET see below example (in example using DateTime.UtcNow, but you can plug in any DateTime you want there)

```
Dim uTime As Double
uTime = (DateTime.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds
```

Comment: This link is broken. Could you please update the link and include the contents in your answer?

Comment: Sure enough, 3 years later and link is broken, updating answer with example code

Comment: Const version:  (DateTime.UtcNow - #1/1/1970#).TotalSeconds  -- Also, Use an Int64 or it will wrap in the year 2038.  Similar to y2k problem.

Comment: as i have faced the problem, i write if it may help others, you should use Long instead of Integer as if you try to get unix value 25/50 years now, it will throw overflow error.

Comment: Might be late, but you should update your answer and refactor the variable from `Integer` to `Long` to avoid the *2038 effect*.

Comment: UTime should be double not an integer. 
".TotalSeconds" returns a double.

Comment: Note: I use the Ameritade API and stumbled upon .TotalSeconds. The API want to have MilliSeconds = .TotalMilliseconds (= + 3 more digits). If I call the API with Seconds, I get a completely weird result back (although, I get the correct date in various online "translater" tools).

Comment: Edit rejected, so commenting. In >= .NET Core 2.1 `DateTime.UnixEpoch` can be used instead of the 1970 DateTime constructor. You'd want to convert the Double returned by `TotalSeconds` to Int64 (ie long/big integer), with `Convert.ToInt64` since unix epoch time is always a whole number. You can do the declaration and assignment on one line, so `Dim unixTime As Int64 = Convert.ToInt64((DateTime.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds)` or in .NET 2.1 `Dim unixTime As Int64 = Convert.ToInt64((DateTime.UtcNow - DateTime.UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds)`

Answer (score 7):

I wrote these at some point - all similar to the above just with a little more detail on the old summer time adjustment thing for me here in the UK.

```
Public Function UnixToTime(ByVal strUnixTime As String) As Date
    UnixToTime = DateAdd(DateInterval.Second, Val(strUnixTime), #1/1/1970#)
    If UnixToTime.IsDaylightSavingTime = True Then
        UnixToTime = DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, 1, UnixToTime)
    End If
End Function

Public Function TimeToUnix(ByVal dteDate As Date) As String
    If dteDate.IsDaylightSavingTime = True Then
        dteDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, -1, dteDate)
    End If
    TimeToUnix = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, #1/1/1970#, dteDate)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/timestamp.aspx it shows unix->.net so you can go backwards most likely:

```
DateTime dt = "the date";
DateTime start= new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

TimeSpan ts = (dt - start);

ts.TotalSeconds //unix timestamp
```

or something similar will do it.

note, this has not been tested by me so it probably wont work :)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, at least, unix timestamps are milliseconds, and I found a case where I needed them. This code makes use of .Net using 10,000 ticks / millisecond. Here's the code I used:

```
Public Module UnixTime
    Const UnixEraStartTicks As Long = 621355968000000000
    <Extension> Public Function UnixTimestamp(value As Date) As Long
        Dim UnixEraTicks = value.Ticks - UnixEraStartTicks
        Return UnixEraTicks \ 10000
    End Function
    Public Function DateFromUnix(timestamp As Long) As Date
        Return New Date(UnixEraStartTicks + timestamp * 10000)
    End Function
End Module
```