# How Can I Display the UNIXTIME on a Chart As Real Time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, unix-timestamp

I have a chart that displays UnixTime

I believe the code for it is the following:
`TimePoint = CType(oRow.Item("TimeStamp"), Long`

Can I re-factor that to display real date time?
Screenshot: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0cd1hy4he8

Comment: possible duplicate of [DateTime to UnixTime Stamp in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942519/datetime-to-unixtime-stamp-in-net)

Comment: other thread is of no use, and info doesn't look useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function ConvertTimestamp(ByVal timestamp as Double) As DateTime
      Return New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(timestamp)
End Function

TimePoint = ConvertTimeStamp( CType(oRow.Item("TimeStamp"), Double)).ToLocalTime()
```

Comment: no error, but no change eithr. Does "ConvertTimestamp" need to be "long"

Comment: Try changing the cast in your original code to a Double: `CType(oRow.Item("TimeStamp"),Double)`

Comment: Are you calling the ConvertTimeStamp function with the TimePoint value and then formatting the DateTime value? I'll add a bit to the answer.

Comment: Thanks but no dice, i have put the page code in JS and Global code in HTML in this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6vxpE/

Comment: Why do you use ToOADate()? It looks like that's why your dates are displayed as decimal OleAutomation dates.