# how to GET request, API with HTTPS vb.net

Tags: vb.net, https, get

I want to send and get information through an API of a website. I tried to get open orders of a cryptocurrency trading website. I have an "API key" and a "secret key" for the API. I tried the vb.net code below, but it gives me an error. I think I need to signing before sending `GET` requests over `https` etc. How to do signing. How to do this?.

**my code**

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey=b30ba2e17fb93a979edc&market=USDT-ADA")
    RichTextBox1.Text = result
End Sub
End Class
```

**Error**

`{"success":false,"message":"NONCE_NOT_PROVIDED","result":null}`

**Following is the information I got from their API guides.**

https://support.bittrex.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003723911

https://github.com/Bittrex/bittrex.github.io

```
For this version, we use a standard HMAC-SHA512 signing. Append apikey and nonce to your request and calculate the HMAC hash and include it under an apisign header. Note: the nonce is not respected right now but will be enforced later.


$apikey='xxx';
$apisecret='xxx'; 
$nonce=time(); 
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce; 
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret); 
$ch = curl_init($uri); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign)); 
$execResult = curl_exec($ch); 
$obj = json_decode($execResult);    


Request

https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey=API_KEY&market=BTC-LTC

Response - Returns you the order uuid


{
    "success" : true,
    "message" : "",
    "result" : [{
            "Uuid" : null,
            "OrderUuid" : "09aa5bb6-8232-41aa-9b78-a5a1093e0211",
            "Exchange" : "BTC-LTC",
            "OrderType" : "LIMIT_SELL",
            "Quantity" : 5.00000000,
            "QuantityRemaining" : 5.00000000,
            "Limit" : 2.00000000,
            "CommissionPaid" : 0.00000000,
            "Price" : 0.00000000,
            "PricePerUnit" : null,
            "Opened" : "2014-07-09T03:55:48.77",
            "Closed" : null,
            "CancelInitiated" : false,
            "ImmediateOrCancel" : false,
            "IsConditional" : false,
            "Condition" : null,
            "ConditionTarget" : null
        }, {
            "Uuid" : null,
            "OrderUuid" : "8925d746-bc9f-4684-b1aa-e507467aaa99",
            "Exchange" : "BTC-LTC",
            "OrderType" : "LIMIT_BUY",
            "Quantity" : 100000.00000000,
            "QuantityRemaining" : 100000.00000000,
            "Limit" : 0.00000001,
            "CommissionPaid" : 0.00000000,
            "Price" : 0.00000000,
            "PricePerUnit" : null,
            "Opened" : "2014-07-09T03:55:48.583",
            "Closed" : null,
            "CancelInitiated" : false,
            "ImmediateOrCancel" : false,
            "IsConditional" : false,
            "Condition" : null,
            "ConditionTarget" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

**P.S: EDIT - I TRIED TO CONVERT THE CODE BUT STILL GETS ERRORS**

**Error: {"success":false,"message":"INVALID_SIGNATURE","result":null}**

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.AccessControl
Imports System.Text

Public Shared Function hashtest(ByRef inputString As String, ByRef key As String) As String

            Dim getmessage = inputString
            Dim getkey As String = key
            Dim encoding As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()
            Dim getkeyByte As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(getkey)
            Using gethmacsha512 As New HMACSHA512(getkeyByte)
                Dim getmessageBytes As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(getmessage)
                Dim hashmessage As Byte() = gethmacsha512.ComputeHash(getmessageBytes)
                Dim Hex_String As String = Bytes_To_String2(hashmessage)
                Return Hex_String

            End Using
        End Function

    Public Shared Function Bytes_To_String2(ByVal bytes_Input As Byte()) As String
            Dim strTemp As New StringBuilder(bytes_Input.Length * 2)
            For Each b As Byte In bytes_Input
                strTemp.Append(Conversion.Hex(b))
            Next
            Return strTemp.ToString()

    End Function

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
            Dim key As String = "xxx"
            Dim secretkey As String = "yyy"
            Dim nonce = (DateTime.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds
            Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
            Dim uri As String = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey=" & key & "&nonce=" & nonce
            Dim sign As String = hashtest(uri, secretkey)

            Dim ourUri As New Uri(uri)
            Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri)
            Dim response As WebResponse
            request.Method = "GET"
            request.Headers.Add("apisign:" & sign)
            response = request.GetResponse()

            Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Dim streamText As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

            RichTextBox1.Text = streamText


        End Sub
```

Comment: The error says `NONCE_NOT_PROVIDED`, and as you see in the example code: `$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;` they send a nonce with the request initialized to the current time in seconds from Jan 1, 1970: `$nonce=time();` (see the PHP [**`time()` function**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)). As for signing, lookup how to create a HMAC-SHA512 hash in .NET.

Comment: @VisualVincent thank you for the reply, hope `HMAC SHA 512` is equivalent to `SHA 512`. Now the problem is I get an error of `{"success":false,"message":"APISIGN_NOT_PROVIDED","result":null}` and I don't know what `'$ch = curl_init($uri); `
    `'curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));`
   `'$execResult = curl_exec($ch);`
   `'$obj = json_decode($execResult);` 
 means. I'm trying to understand and translate that code into vb.net

Comment: No, SHA512 is not the same thing as HMAC-SHA512. The latter is a SHA512 hash constructed with a _message authentication code_ (MAC). See: [HMAC - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC). There is a [**`HMACSHA512` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha512(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET. As for the rest, CURL is just an implementation of making a web request. You'd use a `HttpWebRequest` in .NET. `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` simply adds a header to that web request.

Comment: @VisualVincent I still get errors, I added my code as an edit with `HttpWebRequest`at the bottom of the original post. Please be kind enough to go through it.

Comment: Well first of all, `HMACSHA512` and `newStream` implement `IDisposable`, so you need two wrap the two in [**`Using` blocks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement). Secondly, the nonce should be the number of seconds _since 1970_. `TimeOfDay` only returns _today's_ time (00:00-24:00, or 12 AM-12 PM). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1942536 - Also, **always** post the error messages you get.

Comment: @VisualVincent thank you for the reply. I did the edits. and the `error` is `The URI prefix is not recognized.`

Comment: Further, I think in `HMACsha512` hashing function is incomplete although it seems to work. Because, I didn't provide it with the `secret key` to generate the hash. And `$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);` indicates the hash function is feeded with two seperate inputs, so my code of `Generate_HMACsha512String(uri & secretkey)` should be incorrect code. So it must be generating a wrong hash. How to insert the `secret key` when hashing.

Comment: I just noticed that this is far from correct: `hash.ToString()` - `hash` is a byte array and cannot be converted to a string directly. All your code currently does is returning `System.Byte[]` (that's what the `ToString()` call results in). `hmac_sha` returns its results as a lowecase HEX string. Lookup how to convert a byte array to that in VB.NET.

Comment: As for the inputs, [_**check the official documentation**_](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php). You can find all of these functions by just googling. The first parameter is the text to be hashed, the second is the _key_ to use when hashing. Use [**this `HMACSHA512` constructor**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5y83hkf(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify the latter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174985/discussion-between-visual-vincent-and-pretty-girl).