# Alternative of JavaScript function [Symbol.toPrimitive]('number') in VB.NET

Tags: javascript, vb.net, datetime

Is there any function or way in vb.net to get the date formatted same as if am calling this following javascript Code:

```js
const date = new Date('20 June 2023 14:48');
console.log(date[Symbol.toPrimitive]('number'));
```

Output will be : 1687261680000

I need to do the same in VB.net . I get Now date and need to transform it to save value format as above in order to add it to json file constructed in vb.net

Comment: Seems that your question is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1942519). Just multiply the number of seconds by 1000 to get the number of milliseconds.